# Share Menu Sort Order

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, share-menu

I make frequent use of the Share menu.  Most frequently I share URLs to Pocket so I can read them later, though less frequently I'll share to email, SMS or Facebook Messenger.  Since I've upgraded my Samsung S6 Edge to Marshmallow, I've noticed that when I open the Share menu, frequently there's about a 1 - 2 second delay where Android re-sorts the order of the items on the Share menu.  Perhaps the most frustrating aspect of this behavior is that more often than not, Pocket, my most frequently used target is moved from the first screen of the Share menu to the second while a Hangouts chat with a friend that hasn't been active in over a month is moved to the first item in the list.

My question is this:  Is there any way I can control the sort order of items on the Share menu?

Comment: I'm quite sure this question has been asked here already. It's sorted roughly in order of frequency of use, along with some developer criteria, AFAIK. Look at [this](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/129599/92056) for an interim solution.

Comment: TL; DR - You can use an app like [AndMadeShare](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andmadesoft.share), which is basically a share menu replacement. It works with Marshmallow, and is customizable. If this works for you, drop a comment and I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, it was very annoying. Did not want any share menu replacement apps.
So now found the trick: when the share menu opens, long press on the app - a menu popups with an option to pin it.

Your post is a year old, I guess you might have figured out it already :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  I did actually find another workaround, I ditched Android for iOS :)